# How do I get CruiseControl.NET to show failure when aborting a build?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Currently if I abort a CC.NET build the project last build status is shown as Success, I would prefer it to say Failure. How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can - its has been added in [version 1.6](http://sourceforge.net/news/?group_id=71179) by [design](http://jira.public.thoughtworks.org/browse/CCNET-1211).